# Correspondence between strings with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I need a function in *Python* that takes two strings `(a, b)` and a list of correspondence rules, i.e. pairs of strings `(a[i], b[i])`, and checks whether it is possible to **split `a` in parts, replace each part according to the correspondence rules and get `b`**. The problem is that the rules may be a bit tangled:

1. there may be rules like `(a, b)` and `(a, c)`
2. like `(aa, b)` and `(a, c)`
3. like `(ab, d)` and `(bc, e)`
4. it is correspondence, not replacement (`a` cannot be left `a` or first transform to `b` then to `c`).

For example, if the correspondence rules are `(aa, x)`, `(ab, y)`, `(ab, z)`, then `(aab, anything)`, `(a, anything)` are not accepted, but `(aa, x)`, `(abab, yz)`, `(abab, yy)`, `(abab, zz)`, `(abab, zy)`, (aaab, xy)` are.

Is there a way to use standart *regex* library of *Python* or some other common regular expressions implementation to do it? I am able to do it by brute force, but it will be quite non-effective with many pairs to check.

Comment: You can check if strings are anagrams by comparing their sorted values which is O(n log(n)) time. You can then make custom checks in O(n) time.

Comment: @kilojoules, why anagrams?

Comment: Is it possible to apply the rules repeatedly? For example: Having two rules `(aa, b)` and `(b, a)`, is it possible to reduce `aaaa` to `a`?

Comment: @dlask, no, see comment 4

Comment: You could add examples of the expected behaviour. Considering your rule `(ab, d)` and `(bc, e)`, which of the following pairs is accepted? `(abab, dab)`, `(abab, abd)`, `(abab, dd)`, `(abc, dc)`, `(abc, abe)`, …

Comment: I'm 99% sure regex is useless for this other than the trivial search and replace groups of characters.

Comment: @dlask, yes, I'll do it now.

Comment: You could do this with dynamic programming, by building up prefixes of `a` that match prefixes of `b` and seeing how you can extend them.

Comment: The provided example is good but another example would be required for overlapping patterns like `(ab, d)` and `(bc, e)`.

Comment: @dlask:  It appears the "ciphertext" strings are _not_ allowed to overlap each other.  `('aab', anything)` is one of his examples of a rejected pair, even though both `'aa'` and `'ab'` are allowable ciphertexts.  If they were allowed to overlap, then `'aab'` would have two valid plaintexts: `'xy'` and `'xz'`.  (And presumably, since `'aa'` perfectly overlaps `'aa'`, it could translate into `'x'`, `'xxxx'`, or `'x' * int(float('inf'))`... if that were allowed.)

Answer (score 1):

(To keep the English from getting totally confused, I will refer to the elements of your correspondence pairs as "keys" and "values", even though the repeated keys prevent them from composing a typical `dict`.)

I believe there are several reasons you can't do this with regular expressions alone.

**Problem 1.  RegExes Aren't Maps**

Regular expressions have no way of associating a string made of some sequence of keys with its translation(s) into values.  Just for starters, the `re` functions would need access to your list of key-value pairs, if only so it could tell you which keys appeared in a match.

**Problem 2:  Ambiguous Matches**

There are a couple ways regular expressions can deal with ambiguous matches in an alternation like:

```python3
re.findall(r'(a|aa|aaa)*', 'aaaa')
```

The problem is, you only get to pick *one* of them for any given regex.  Your question requires tracking *which* of those alternatives matched, in what order, and how many times each.

Worse, your question requires knowing all possible combinations of those alternatives that match.  But once a regular expression determines that `'aaaa'` matches *any* repetition, like `'a' + 'a' + 'a' + 'a'`, it's *done* --- match found.

But *you* aren't done yet.  You still have to test all the other matches, like `'a' + 'a' + 'aa'`, and `'a' + 'aa' + 'a'`, and `'aaa' + 'a'`, and...  Testing those will result in *many* different combinations of values getting glued together and compared to your second argument.  You can't skip them.

**A Valiant but Doomed Attempt**

I made a regex-building function that can identify valid input and output strings, for a set of key-value pairs.  Unfortunately, that says nothing about whether the given input string could actually produce a specific output.

```python3
import re

def is_valid_word(word, alphabet):
    '''
    Returns True if the given word can be assembled from zero or
    more of the strings in the given alphabet.  If word is an
    empty string (''), this is True regardless of strings in the
    alphabet.
    '''
    regex_letters = (re.escape(letter) for letter in alphabet)
    regex_alternatives = '|'.join(regex_letters)
    regex = r'(?:' + regex_alternatives + r')' + r'*' + r'$'
    # regex looks like:  r'(?:a|b|aa|ab|abc)*$'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    match = pattern.match(word)
    return match is not None

def is_valid_key_word(word, pairs):
    keys = set(pair[0] for pair in pairs)
    return is_valid_word(word, alphabet=keys)

def is_valid_value_word(word, pairs):
    values = set(pair[1] for pair in pairs)
    return is_valid_word(word, alphabet=values)
```

This can quickly(?) rule out *impossible* input or output strings, but it can't actually solve your problem, and if there's enough backtracking, it won't even be fast.

Stick with `for` loops.